# Get subclass back when stored as superclass

Tags: java, class, reflection

So I've been trying to fix this for a few hours now, to no avail.

Basically, I have class `A`, and class `B` which extends `A`. `A` has a string field "name", and another field "id", class `B` changes `name` when instantiated. `B` is then later stored as `A`, and the only thing identifying that `A` class to the `B` class is the "id" field.

I need a way to get the changed "name" that the B class has, from the A class.

Here's a code example:

```
class A {
    public String name = "test";
    public String id = "A_ID";
    
    public A(String id) {
        if (id.equals("B_ID") {
            // how would I get the name field of the B class, without instantiating B
        }
    }
}
class B extends A {
    {
        name = "test1";
        id = "B_ID";
    }
}
```

And here's what I've tried:

```
class A {
    public static Map<String, Class<? extends A>> REGISTRY = new HashMap<>();
    
    public String name = "test";
    public String id = "A_ID"; // is B_ID when changed
    
    public Object getField(String key) {
        Field field = REGISTRY.get(this.id).getSuperclass().getDeclaredField(key);
        return field.get(this); // <- the issue
    }
}
class B extends A {
    static {
        REGISTRY.put("B_ID", B.class);
    }
    public B() {
        name = "test1";
        id = "B_ID";
    }

}
```

Here's the problem with my solution, passing `this` to `field.get(this)` returns the fields of the current A object, which is what we already have. I need the fields that `B` changes when instantiated, but when `B` gets instantiated it calls `getField` a few times, which then causes a perpetual loop, I need a way to get the fields from `B` without instantiating `B`.

I've tried casting `A` to `B` but that causes a ClassCastException.

Sorry that this is confusing, I can't send the entire class as it's literally 1k+ lines, but basically the ID field is the only data stored with A that remains from B, and I need a way to get the fields from B without instantiating it

EDIT: I think my example was confusing, here's an example of how pkm's answer still presents the issue.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class A {
    public static Map<String, Class<? extends A>> REGISTRY = new HashMap<>();

    public String name = "test";
    public String id; // is B_ID when changed

    public A(String id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.getField("name") // should output test1
    }

    public Object getField(String key) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException,
            IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        Field field = REGISTRY.get(this.id).getSuperclass().getDeclaredField(key);
        return field.get(this); // <- the issue, still returns "test"
    }
}


class B extends A {
    static {
        REGISTRY.put("B_ID", B.class);
    }

    public B() {
        super("B_ID");
        name = "test1";
    }
}

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException,
            IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        new B(); // To update the registry
        A a = new A("B_ID");
        System.out.println(a.id);                //--> output: B_ID
        System.out.println(a.getField("name"));      //--> output: test, should be test1
    }

}
```

Comment: Is check ` if (this instanceof B)` not enough?

Comment: Like I said, it's all stored as A. Nothing is an instance of B, so downcasting to B causes a ClassCastException

Comment: “Nothing is an instance of B”—except of the instance you created via `new B()`, of course. Since the code you’ve posted changes the field of that `B` instance, but you don’t keep a reference to that object, it is impossible to retrieve the value with that code. It’s not clear why you are using Reflection here, perhaps, only to hide the fundamental logical error of trying to get a value you’ve abandoned. But since all instances invariably get this value in the constructor, you could use `REGISTRY.get("B_ID").getConstructor().newInstance().name` to get the value, but it’s still overengineered.

Comment: I instantiate B, but the object is serialized to JSON and deserialized later back into A, which is what I meant by "it's all stored as A"

Comment: You somehow forgot to mention that your problem is about JSON serialization. Besides that, what is the problem? The field is declared in `A`, so after deserializing the `A` instance, it still will contain the *value* that was stored in the original `B` instance prior to serialization. Of course, since your example code does not contain any serialization/deserialization, this does not happen in the example code. In your example, there are no instances, but only a registry of *classes* and constants provided by constructors, which wouldn’t need persistence at all.

Comment: Recommended read [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class A {
  public static Map<String, Class<? extends A>> REGISTRY = new HashMap<>();

  public String name = "test";
  public String id = "A_ID"; // is B_ID when changed

  public Object getField(String key) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException,
      IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    Field field = REGISTRY.get(this.id).getSuperclass().getDeclaredField(key);
    return field.get(this); // <- the issue
  }
}


class B extends A {
  static {
    REGISTRY.put("B_ID", B.class);
  }

  public B() {
    name = "test1";
    id = "B_ID";
  }

}


public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException,
      IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    A a = new B();
    System.out.println(a.name);                //--> output: test1
    System.out.println(a.getField("id"));      //--> output: B_ID
  }
}
```

As per your statement: `I need a way to get the changed "name" that the B class has, from the A class.` It'a achieved correctly, B_ID.

Comment: My example was poorly explained, I apologize. I've updated my question to reflect how your answer still presents the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by changing the registry from `Class<? extends A>` to just `A`, and then registering a new instance of `B`. I think it might lead to issues down the road and I was avoiding doing this but it works for now.